# Series of node commands hangs on npx command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a node script whose job is to scaffold an app I've built. It creates files and folders then runs a series of node commands. All works perfectly. These are the commands that are run:

```
const postInstCmds = [
    'npm init -y',
    'npm install http-server --save-dev',
    'npx add-npm-scripts server "http-server"',
    'npm run server'
];
postInstCmds.forEach(cmd => execSync(cmd, {cwd: appDir}));
console.log('Done!');
```

However, in the terminal, it seems to hang on the penultimate (`npx`) command, even though it *does* run the final `npm run server` command (because the created app is available on localhost:8080). For presumably the same reason I never see my "Done!" log. This is what I see:

[image]

How can I get the terminal to complete the commands without hanging on the `npx` one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never see "Done" because the *last* command never exits. The penultimate command does in fact exit. We know this because otherwise the last command wouldn't run (since you are using `execSync()` and that will block until the command exits) and you would not have your server running.

What appears to be happening is that you are only seeing STDERR and not STDOUT. Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't say exactly why that is happening, but a potential easy fix could be to specify that all stdio should be inherited.

```
postInstCmds.forEach(cmd => execSync(cmd, {cwd: appDir, stdio: 'inherit'}));
```

Comment: Thank you - just what I needed. Would you mind explaining a little more about what this tweak does?

Comment: You can read about the different values for the `stdio` option at https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio. The `inherit` value means to pass stdio from the child process to the corresponding stdio of the parent.